# How to check result of alcDestroyContext

Tags: openal

Is there a direct way to check the result of `alcDestroyContext`?

If I call `alGetError()` I get `AL_INVALID_OPERATION` but I beleve it's because `alGetError()` needs to be called on a correct context.

So, how could I check that `alcDestroyContext` was successful? Or even, should I check it?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done when the application terminates (so that it terminates "gracefully), but at that point there's really not much you can do about it, so I wouldn't worry.

```
void Shutdown() const
{
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(context);
    alcCloseDevice(device);
}
```

This is called before I quit the application. I think it's acceptable. Even if something goes wrong with the shutdown procedure, the OS will reclaim the memory used. Life goes on.

But I asked around, and a better solution is:

```
void Shutdown() const
{
    ALCboolean check = alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    if (!check)
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]::alcMakeContextCurrent() failed to make current context NULL.\n";

    alcDestroyContext(context);
    ALenum err = alcGetError(device);
    if (err != AL_NO_ERROR)
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]::alcDestroyContext() error: " << alcGetString(device, err) << std::endl;

    check = alcCloseDevice(device);
    if (!check)
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]::alcCloseDevice() failed to close the device.\n";

    while (!check || err)
    {
        // Wait here indefinitely (until closing it manually) to have enough time
        // to see the error message displayed in the console
    }
}
```

I got a `AL lib: (WW) 6 Sources not deleted` message when testing this, which reminds me that I need to loop through my sources and terminate them, as well.

Also, if you run this on a device that doesn't have a console window (e.g. on a tablet) you should display a message on the screen from that 'while' loop, otherwise it will seem like the application froze.